# The centralizer and normalizer of $U(n)$ in $SU(n+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, quotient-spaces

> **Question: What is the [centralizer and normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) of $U(n)$ in $SU(n+1)$?**

(Thanks in advance for your comments/answers!)

---

We can embed $U(n)$ in $SU(n+1)$ in the following way:

Take $U(n)=\frac{SU(n) \times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}/n}$,
and write the group element in $U(n)$ as $g_{U(n)} \in U(n)$ such that
$$
g_{U(n)} =(a_{SU(n)}, b_{U(1)} )
$$
with the constraint that
$$
\det a_{SU(n)}=1.
$$
The $\mathbb{Z}/n$ center of $SU(n)$ is identified with the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/n \in U(1)$. For example,
$$\text{  if  } a_{SU(n)}= \exp(\frac{2 \pi i}{n})\mathbb{I}_{n\times n},
\text{  then  } b_{U(1)} = \exp(\frac{2 \pi i}{n}) \text{ is identified with as the same group action by } a_{SU(n)}.
$$
Now the $g_{U(n)} =(a_{SU(n)}, b_{U(1)} )  \in U(n)$ can be written as the group element
$$
g_{SU(n+1)} = \begin{pmatrix} 
g_{U(n)} & 0\\
0 &  (b_{U(1)})^{-n}
\end{pmatrix}
\in SU(n+1)
$$
so that $\det g_{SU(n+1)}=\det g_{U(n+1)}(b_{U(1)})^{-n}=b_{U(1)}^n b_{U(1)}^{-n}=1$ as desired.

Comment: That is a really long-winded way of saying $g\mapsto[\begin{smallmatrix}g&0\\0&(\det g)^{-1}\end{smallmatrix}]$.

Comment: Thanks so much you are smarter on this! +1

Answer (score 1):

So the embedding $U(n)\to SU(n+1)$ is simply $g\mapsto[\begin{smallmatrix}g&0\\0&(\det g)^{-1}\end{smallmatrix}]$.

Suppose $x\in N_{SU(n+1)}(U(n))$. For any $\tau\in U(n)$, we know $x\tau x^{-1}$ is in $U(n)$, so $x\tau x^{-1}$ must have $e_{n+1}$ as an eigenvector, which implies $x^{-1}e_{n+1}$ must be a simultaneous eigenvector of all $\tau\in U(n)$. That implies that $x^{-1}e_{n+1}$ is a multiple of $e_{n+1}$, or in other words $e_{n+1}$ is a simultaneous eigenvector of all $x$ in the normalizer, which in turn implies $N_{SU(n+1)}(U(n))=U(n)$, i.e. $U(n)$ is self-normalizing.

Thus the centralizer is the center $Z(U(n))$. This consists of $[\begin{smallmatrix}\lambda I_n &0\\0& \lambda^{-n} \end{smallmatrix}]$ with $\lambda\in S^1$.